# Boot to text mode

Tags: tty

How can I boot directly to tty3 without seeing any GUI (login screen of gnome)? I don't want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> on every startup.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specifically tty3 but,
In a terminal...
`sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

will take you straight to the console on boot...

...and if this is not what you wanted

`sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` will bring back your desktop on boot...

Comment: Can I switch to gnome-shell back?

Comment: @maDeveloper yes... if you can `sudo init 5` or `startx` and it will start your graphical desktop session from there.

Comment: thanks thanks, and another question; is there a variable that shows tty number?

Comment: ..... `who am i`